# Is there a book/online resource that contains only multiple choice questions on Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Is there a book/online resource that contains only multiple choice questions on Complex Analysis?  I checked MSE and found only three (3) posts containing some multiple choice questions.  I also checked Google, and did not find any book/online resources.

Something like an online quiz applet or (commercial) E-Book would be great!  But a book on this topic (available in major book stores/shops, preferably locally) would be awesome as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about containing *only* multiple choice, but you could possibly make up your own from the problems/exercises and solutions in the following:

1. [Schaum's Outline](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071615695)
2. [Alpay](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9783034800785)

Comment: Thanks, @g.s!  =)